# Show date 3 days later than Date Picker date in text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using this date picker code.

```
var d = new Date();
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: d,
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
    });
});
```

What I need is if I select a date then I a date 3 days later comes into the next text field. For example. I select a date **02-12-2016** and in the next text field the date is **02-15-2016**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question is below :

Just Replace the 3 with the no. of days u want to add

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#inp_date').datepicker();
    });

    function getdate() {

        var tt = document.getElementById('inp_date').value;

        var date = new Date(tt);
        var newdate = new Date(date);

        newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 3);

        var dd = newdate.getDate();
        var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = newdate.getFullYear();

        var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
        document.getElementById('output_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="inp_date" type="text" /><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Fill Follow Date" /><hr>

    <input id="output_Date" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI i need to edit my code and add something in it because i am using date picker

Comment: and also i dont want to click on fill follow date and also i need previous dates to be disabled

Comment: Then instead of using onclick do `$('#inp_date').on('change', getdate)`, and disable the previous input within `getdate()`. This answer already shows you how to tackle your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to add 3 days to the current date

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days'));
```

then echo **$date** as value in your text field..

**note: this is done in php.**

Comment: $a=02-12-2016;
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days'));

how can i add 3 days in $a using your code i am confused

Comment: sorry for the late response.. `$date='02-12-2016';
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.'+3 days'));
echo $newdate;` hope it helps...